# Rendering sprites in Libgdx on tilemap

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tile

I'm trying to render a sprite/texture on top of a tiled map in libgdx/android studio. Note that my map is 20x25 with 8 pixel tiles and splitTiles is a Texture Region.

```
 public void show() {

    cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 20, 25);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("centipedeMap.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,1/8f)
}

  public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.setView(cam);
    renderer.render();
    player.update();
    ex.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    cam.update();

    batch.begin();
    Texture tilesImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tile.png"));
    TextureRegion[][] splitTiles = TextureRegion.split(tilesImage, 8, 8);
    batch.draw(splitTiles[0][0],50,50);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Sorry for being vague, my sprite is not showing up on top of the tiled map. The tile map is rendering but the sprite is not.

Comment: Are you able to draw simple textureRegion instead of Splited TextureRegion ? and don't create `Texture` object in `render` method.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekAryan, I initialized the Texture/TextureRegion in the `show` method and it worked! What I don't understand is that the x and y coordinates of the batch corresponds to the cell. For example '        batch.draw(image,2,2,1,1);' puts the image where the cell 2,2 resides. Currently I place random tiles over the map and I set Rectangles for collisions and I put the Rectangles for example if `Cell=(1,1)` then I place the rectangle at (1*8,1*8). Should I place the rectangles at (1,1) or should i do (1*8,1*8). Thank you so much, please post an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your camera viewport dimension is 20, 25 and you're drawing your TextureRegion at 50,50 so your image is rendered out of screen so not visible.

Recommendation : [Texture](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Textures,-textureregion-and-spritebatch#texture) is heavy object so try to avoid creating multiple instance of same Texture.

you've camera viewport is in dimension of 20,25 that is same as tileMap(20,25) dimension so camera 1 unit denotes one cell of TileMap.

you can detect collision with Tiles,it is not necessary to create Rectangle object.

Comment: Should it be something like this-
   `if (layer.getCell(x, y) != null &&` `layer.getCell(x,y).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("Blocked")) {`
       `do something`                                                                                          `}`

Comment: player always surrounding by eight cell , check your player is going to collide that cell. check that cell having what property or id, depending on that do your action.